# Transparent annotation for html code

Tags: html, metadata, translation

I have a dynamically created web page. Most of the text is inserted using a translation mechanism. But of course now the text has to be translated first. So in addition to bulk translation in a separate tool, I want to allow that to happen right there in the page the translation will be displayed.

So what (I think) I need to do is, somehow mark the text, that should be translated and use javascript to create a button that displays the translation widget and fills out the meta-information. So far so good. The problem is, that the text may not only appear in textnodes inside of html nodes, but also in attributes. That is why my ideas (using some html tag like `<translate metadata=.../>` or even using html comments) do not work. Also it is not feasible to say "put this data outside of the current html-tag", because the translation routine is used all over the code.

Is there another way to transparently put meta-information inside the html code? Maybe invisible unicode characters? (I'm using utf-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself, using zero-length unicode characters.

The three characters `\u200B` (zero width space, ZWSP), `\u200C` (zero width non-joiner, ZWNJ) and `\u200D` (zero width joiner, ZWJ) are control characters which should be invisible. I chose ZWSP as boundary indicator for disambiguation, ZWNJ as binary `0` AND ZWJ as binary `1`. In PHP this means encoding an annotation id `$nr` is done as:

```
$binnr = decbin($nr);
$annotation = "&#x200B;";
for($i=0; $i<strlen($binnr); $i++)
    $annotation .= '&#x200'.($binnr{$i}=="0"?"c":"d").';';
$annotation .= '&#x200b;';
```

It is probably better to use the actual characters instead of html entities. So we need

```
return html_entity_decode($annotation, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

I'm collecting the meta-data which belong to those ids in a separate array and put it into the page head. Then on the javascript side of the story the DOM tree is searched for the encoded annotations with:

```
function parse_numbers(text)
{
    read = false;
    nrs = []; nr = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<text.length; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == "\u200B") {
            read = !read;
            if(!read) {
                nrs.push(nr);
                nr = 0;
            }
        } else if(text[i] == "\u200C") {
            nr <<= 1;
        } else if(text[i] == "\u200D") {
            nr <<= 1; nr++;
        }
    }
    return nrs;
}

function buttons_recursive(node, insert)
{
    nrs = [];
    switch(node.nodeType)
    {
        case 1: //ELEMENT_NODE:
            for(var i=0; i<node.attributes.length; i++) {
                nrs.concat(buttons_recursive(node.attributes[i], false));
            }
            var new_insert = insert;
            if(node.nodeName == "BUTTON" || node.nodeName == "A") {
                new_insert = false;
            }
            for(var i=0; i<node.childNodes.length; i++) {
                nrs.concat(buttons_recursive(node.childNodes[i], new_insert));
            }
            break;
        case 2: //ATTRIBUTE_NODE:
            nrs = parse_numbers(node.value);
            break;
        case 3: //TEXT_NODE:
            nrs = parse_numbers(node.nodeValue);
            break;
        default:
            return [];
    }
    if(insert) {
        for(var i=nrs.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(create_inline_button(nrs[i]), node.nextSibling);
        }
        return [];
    } else {
        return nrs;
    }
}
```

by executing

```
buttons_recursive(document.body, true);
```

The function `create_inline_button` should create the control element to initiate translation of the text with a given identifier.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5, there is the global [`translate` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-translate-attribute):

> The `translate` attribute is an enumerated attribute that is used to specify whether an element's attribute values and the values of its Text node children are to be translated when the page is localized, or whether to leave them unchanged.

You would have to add `translate="no"` to every element that *shouldn't* be translated (note that child elements inherit the value).

For the corner case where attribute values should be translated but not the element content, you could add a `span` element around the content, e.g.:

```
<b title="translate this, please" translate="yes"><span translate="no">Don't translate this</span></b>
```

---

For more complex cases you could have a look at the [W3C Recommendation **Internationalization Tag Set (ITS)**](http://www.w3.org/TR/its/).

Comment: Thank you, your answer was quite insightful. Nevertheless it does not solve the problem, as such a solution would have to be integrated from the beginning of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel. Google has an awesome translation API that I think you should be using.

https://developers.google.com/translate/

Comment: As far as I have read your reference, it has nothing to do with what I'm trying to achieve. I'm not looking for automatic translation, but for building a tool for human translators.